# Mounting partition to /mnt does not work

Tags: partitioning, mount, 15.10

I have four partition in my hard drive. I have set them to be mounted automatically on startup on "/mnt/partition_1", "/mnt/partition_2", "/mnt/partition_3" and "/mnt/partition_4". I did all this through the disk GUI in Ubuntu 15.10. When I try to do "cd /mnt/partition_1" got the message no file with such name exists. What I'm I doing wrong and how can it be solved?

My /etc/fstab contents

```
# /etc/fstab: static file system information.
#
# Use 'blkid' to print the universally unique identifier for a
# device; this may be used with UUID= as a more robust way to name devices
# that works even if disks are added and removed. See fstab(5).
#
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
# / was on /dev/sda1 during installation
UUID=b4f0caa6-f0b1-4c8c-a3ea-2475abe36c7a /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
# swap was on /dev/sda5 during installation
UUID=062adf53-8ac1-44a2-92b7-977ac8af3402 none            swap    sw              0       0
/dev/fd0        /media/floppy0  auto    rw,user,noauto,exec,utf8 0       0
/dev/disk/by-uuid/36529EBE0BF46E54 /mnt/ auto nosuid,nodev,nofail,x-gvfs-show,x-gvfs-name=partition_1 0 0
/dev/disk/by-uuid/09837FDF492C4AE0 /mnt/ auto nosuid,nodev,nofail,x-gvfs-show,x-gvfs-name=partition_2 0 0
/dev/disk/by-uuid/0AB956653B7DF0A1 /mnt/ auto nosuid,nodev,nofail,x-gvfs-show,x-gvfs-name=partition_3 0 0
/dev/disk/by-uuid/314098B075FD9233 /mnt/ auto nosuid,nodev,nofail,x-gvfs-show,x-gvfs-name=partition_4 0 0
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `/etc/fstab` file is showing that the partitions are all trying to mount to `/mnt/` rather than `/mnt/partition_#`. You could edit the /etc/fstab file by hand to correct this, adding the partition directory name after the `/mnt/` in the bottom 4 lines of the file, but you **must save a copy of the file first**. Your system may cease to function if you mess up the editing of the file. It's not advisable to do this unless you're confidant of your actions. You can find the UUID for each disk partition using the `sudo blkid` command.

It is probably more sensible to try to use the GUI tool again, and ensure that there are no spaces between `/mnt/` and `partition_#`. You may also need to make the partition directories first, but I'm not sure that's necessary